# Returning with if else statements

Tags: if-statement, methods, return

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PracticeQuestionWK4 {
    private static double computeDifference(double first, double second) {
        if (first <= second) {
            System.out.println("First double must be greater than second double, please try again.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(first - second);
        }
        return first - second;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first double: ");
        double firstDouble = myScanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter second double: ");
        double secondDouble = myScanner.nextDouble();
        computeDifference(firstDouble, secondDouble);
    }

}
```

This code feels awkward. Is there a purpose using private static double instead of private static void here? The question I'm answering calls for a return but it seems redundant. What should I do? EDIT: Sorry the question also calls for the print function to be in it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a calculation function, you should simply use its result.

```
double result = computeDifference(firstDouble, secondDouble);
System.out.print("Result: " + result);
```

Inside the function there normally should be no output.
Conventionally for really erroneous function arguments, one should throw an exception:

```
private static double computeDifference(double first, double second) {
    if (first <= second) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "First double must be greater than second double: "
                + first + " and " + second);
    }
    return first - second;
}
```

In this case maybe check the parameters *before* the call.

Using such functions should not flood the console with insensible output.
(It would slow calculations too.)
Throwing an exception, aborting the application, like with division by zero,
is a form of *fail-fast*. Allowing the developer to find and repair errors fast.
Here it would mean, that the input must be checked first.

If exceptions are still not taught (assuming you are in a programmer's course),
then only in the error case do a println, and return 0 or such.